# EasyAdminBundle: Add a custom view that's not based on entity

Tags: css, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm currently experimenting with [EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle):
I want to add a menu item that calls a custom controller and renders a view. The view is **not** based on an entity but should rather display the results of a csv import.

What I have done so far is:

- create Controller and render the results into a new twig template.
- add the menu item to config and call my Controller with the option
  'route'

The twig template is pretty basic for now. It extends from "EasyAdminBundle:default:layout.html.twig" and overwrites the block "main" in order to display the import results.

Now my problem is that it does not seem to find the css for the layout twig?
My results show a plain html page without any formatting :(
Any hints or suggestions how I can render the view with all the styles from the default views?
Also note: I don't want to overwrite the default layout template for the whole backend and I also don't have a specific entity where I could assign a special layout file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, show us your problematic template to help you.

Comment: `{% extends 'EasyAdminBundle:default:layout.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}
{% for row in rows %}
    {{ row }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}`

Answer (score 0):

found the problem. So the setup as described was ok except that we had some internal project config (that I was not aware of), that would make the response to be returned as json instead of html.